# Image from UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview

is there any Possibility to create a image out of a UIView?

Thanks,
Andreas

Answer (score 47):

`#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"` after you added the framework to your project. Then do:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourView.frame.size);
[[yourView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// The result is *screenshot
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I was looking for.

(You missed a ";")

Answer (score 1):

I have used the answer to improve it even further. Unfortunately, the original code only produced a mirrored image.

So here's the working code:

```
- (UIImage *) imageFromView:(UIView *)view {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, view.size.height);
    // passing negative values to flip the image
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    [[appDelegate.scatterPlotView layer] renderInContext:currentContext];
    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return screenshot;
}
```