# How can I get Image (.png) waveform from audiofile use EZAudio

Tags: ios, objective-c, ezaudio

I can show a waveform in AudioPlot Frame, but I could not get it in the form of pictures. EZAudio has such a method? And how can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EZAudio doesn't have such a method.
You can try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495396/598812) from [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130580/tim) (copied below for convenience).

```
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h" after you added the framework to your project. Then do:

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourView.frame.size);
[[yourView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// The result is *screenshot
```