# How to take screenshot of current screen/UIView including layers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer, avplayerlayer

In my iOS application, i have added AVPlayerLayer as sublayer in myview.layer. For my requirement, i have to take the screenshot of this particular view. If i take the screenshot of this particular view, layer part is not included in the screenshot. And also i can't see this layer inside myview in Xcode preview option.  Anyone please give your suggestion to accomplish this issue.

Ps: I have tried all the methods in this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview).

But all those methods exclude this CALayer.

**EDITED CONTENT:**

I need the screenshot of my UIView with the included layer(AVPlayerLayer). There are lot of options to take screenshot of UIView. But none of these option helps me. So i posted this question to resolve my issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image from UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495370/image-from-uiview)

Comment: Have you find any solution for this issue @santhosh

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495396/598812) from [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130580/tim) should work perfectly (copied below for convenience).

```
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h" after you added the framework to your project. Then do:

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourView.frame.size);
[[yourView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// The result is *screenshot
```

Comment: No, it's not working. It takes the screenshot of yourView without the layer above that view.